# Get COUNT of data at the current hour of system date

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

I have a table of data in Access [image: database table]
DateTimeLog has date/time datatype while the other rest are string.

I need to get the total number of row of data at the last hour of system date with specified ModelLog. But I could not think of a correct structure of the query using MS Access as I am very new to MS Access.

Below shows how I insert the data:

```
  DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
  var today = now.ToString("g");
  DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(today);

  const string sql = @"INSERT INTO timer(DateTimeLog, ShiftLog, CTLog, WorkcellLog, ModelLog, StationLog)VALUES(@d, @shift, @ct, @wc, @wm, @ws)";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@d", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = d;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@shift", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = shiftlb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ct", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = timerlb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@wc", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = wclb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@wm", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mlb.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ws", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = slb.Text;

try
{}
catch(exception e)
{}
```

Comment: The Date/Time can be `var dtm = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(DateTime.Now.Hour - 1);` (add minutes, eventually). Do you have a query that already tries to get Rows from your db? Are you using Command Parameters to pass values to the query? You need two Parameters, one of type `OleDbType.Date` and one of type `OleDbType.VarWChar`, assuming you're using OleDb.  Or is it ODBC? -- Post your code.

Comment: @Jimi Hi there. I have edited the question

Comment: @Jimi I have no problem with getting with specified ModelLog. But I cannot get the current date. I tried using DateTime today = Datetime.Today and Format(DateTimeLog, "Short Date") = today in where clause but it is not working. I also tried separating the column of DateTimeLog to DateLog and TimeLog but i couldnt insert the time only as DateTime in Access

Comment: `OleDbType.DBTimeStamp` is not your format. That's an ISO format for date literals. You need `OleDbType.Date` and `OleDbType.VarWChar` for the strings (Unicode, here). -- The query you're showing is an INSERT query, not a SELECT query, while your question is *I need to get the total number of row of data. [...]*, get, not set. Plus, you're referring to two parameters, a Date/Time  >= a specific date and a text Column + a COUNT() function. Clarify.

Comment: @Jimi Of course the question is about select. The insertion query i showed is to let you know that I used parameter to do the insertion. Yes,  the query is something like count(id) from timer where id in (select id from timer where date/time= now and ModelLog=mlb.Text) But obviously this query is wrong, it's my idea of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you clearly know how to run a database query with parameters, you just need to run this query as `ExecuteScalar`, casting the result to an int

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timer WHERE dateTimeLog >= @d
```

And then set your d parameter to an hour ago

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@d", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
```

Side note I would recommend not round tripping via string just to cut the seconds off a time. Instead consider:

```
var d = DateTime.Now;
d = d.AddTicks( -(d.Ticks % (60*TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)));
```

Or maybe

```
var d = DateTime.Now;
d = d.AddMilliseconds(-d.Milliseconds).AddSeconds(-d.Seconds);
```

Comment: Hi I tried your code and but I get Datatype mismatch in criteria expression. I want to show how I did, should I edit in question or

Comment: I fixed the error. I removed if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()>0) and now it works. Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to use ExecuteScalar to retrieve the count, not ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Side note, you'd do yourself a lot of favours by installing SQL Express and using it instead of Access

Comment: yes you're right. I am forced to use Access because of certain reasons in my company

Answer (score 0):

I found out another way of getting the number of data within the same hour. Create two new columns, HourID and TodayDate both represent current hour in 24hours format and today's date respectively. Insert the data accordingly.

Getting count of data:

```
const string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timer WHERE HourID = @h AND TodayDate = @td AND ModelLog = @m";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@h", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("%H");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@td", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@m", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = mlb.Text;
```